# Dropzone.js not working with Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone in conjunction with Bootstrap and Django, the dropzone actually appears in Safari and Firefox, but does not show up correctly in Chrome. I'm using Chrome version 45.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Metadata</title>
    {% load staticfiles %}

    <link href="{% static 'main/css/bootstrap.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="{% static 'main/css/dropzone.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

  <!-- Main component -->
  <div>
    <form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="myDropzone">
        <!--<button id="submit-all"> Submit all files </button> -->
    </form>


  </div>

</div> <!-- /container -->


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'main/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<!-- DROPZONE -->
<script src="{% static 'main/js/dropzone.js' %}"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Same here, did you found a solution ?

Comment: Not yet, just working with safari/firefox instead until a solution is found.